# Re-initialising a list

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries that is initialised by a call to a function with:

```
new = {'device_id':name,'device_mac':mac, 'device_ttl':ttl}
dev[0] = new
```

Thereafter, new entries are appended with:

```
dev.append(new)
```

Each dictionary has a time to live (TTL). Once that is reached the dictionary is removed:

```
for i in dev:
    if (i['device_ttl'] == 0):
        dev.remove(i)
```

This all seems fine until the list is completely empty. If I then try and add a new entry with:

```
dev[0] = new
```

again, I get a 'list index out of range' error.

I've tried changing the original initialisation with an append to an empty list, but that bombs out immediately with a KeyError: device_id.

The entire function that adds entries is:

```
# Adds a new device to the list of known devices.
def add_device(dev, num, name, mac, ttl):
    new = {'device_id':name,'device_mac':mac, 'device_ttl':ttl}
    if (num == 0):
        #dev.append(new)
        #dev = new
        dev[0] = new
    else:
        dev.append(new)
    return (num + 1)
```

The essential part of the main routine is:

```
devices = [{}] # Empty list.
num_devices = 0

# Code that determines whether to add to the list or not

num_devices = add_device(devices, num_devices,\
                         name_long, mac_address, ttl_n)
```

I don't understand why initialising by appending to an empty list is problematic, nor why what does work to initialise, doesn't work when the list is empty. It is created as empty in the first place!

Is there a better way to initialise or append to an empty list?

Comment: `for i in dev:
    if (i['device_ttl'] == 0):
        dev.remove(i)` don't do this: removing while iterating

Comment: also if the list is empty `dev[0] = new` doesn't work...

Comment: Why can't you use `dev.append()`, always? Why the need to assign to `0`?

Comment: Side note: do not remove elements from a list *while iterating*. If you remove an element at the current or smaller index, everything after that point *shifts up*, but the loop index counter does not. This will lead to your loop 'skipping' items.

Comment: *"It is created as empty in the first place!"* It can't be, else `dev[0] = new` would fail the first time round as well

Comment: Note: when you were doing the `dev[0] = new`, you were not adding the `new` to the exiting list, instead you were replacing the element at 0th index of the list, I doubt that it was expected behavior for you. Instead you should be doing `dev.append(new)`

Comment: And the obvious work-around is to use `if not dev:` to test if it is empty.

Comment: Initialise your list with `dev = [{'device_id':name,'device_mac':mac, 'device_ttl':ttl}]`

Comment: The point regarding removing while iterating is taken but I'm not sure how to tackle that just yet. The reason for that approach was because this is my first Python program and I am finding the referencing of specific fields within an array of dictionaries quite difficult to understand.

Comment: Initialising my list with dev = [{'device_id':name,'device_mac':mac, 'device_ttl':ttl}] doesn't work. I don't know those parameters at the start so have to pass an empty dev into the function. I've tried dev.append but it doesn't work if dev is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to not declare an empty list of dictionaries ,but just an empty list. A number of respondents pointed out the error but did not elucidate an answer.

Declaring an empty list of dictionaries with:

```
devices=[{}]
```

Creates an empty list with an empty dictionary. Assigning the first dictionary with:

```
dev[0] = new
```

just replaced the empty dictionary. Hence why the same assignment doesn't work when the list is emptied.

The correct initialisation was to just declare:

```
devices = []
```

Adding any dictionary after that, including the first one, is by using an append in the function:

```
dev.append(new)
```

Thanks for all of the pointers. I found the answer by switching IDE from Atom to Idle for testing. I have to use Atom as it is the only IDE with the PyCom plugin. Idle flagged the error almost immediately.